# Flexbox: space-between ведет себя как space-around

Tags: css, flexbox

В коде ничего лишнего:

```
.slider-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.slider {
  width: 580px;
}
```

Результат на прилагаемом скрине. Если применить flexbox к дочернему элементу — блоки растягиваются по ширине, игнорируя отступы и `max-width: 580px`.

[image]

Comment: Добавьте html и css в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое поведение чаще всего вызывается тем, что у контейнера могут быть псевдоэлементы **::after** или **::before**. Они могут добавляться, например, в стилях Bootstrap. Флексбок даже псевдоэлементы принимает за дочерние, поэтому включает в выравнивание. Отсюда и возникает этот эффект, когда кажется, что **space-between** ведет себя неправильно.

Comment: В таком случае, это Slick-slider добавляет псевдоэлементы. Bootstrap  я не использовал

Comment: Однако, на скриншоте в вопросе видно, что bootstrap.min.css подключен. И именно для класса .container в бутстрапе имеются псевдоклассы.

Comment: Да, действительно. Вот в другом проекте, отключаю и становится все как положено http://joxi.ru/52aR6P3f4d36pA А с ними - space-around http://joxi.ru/8235BlDHJGjEvr

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, дело в том, что у `.slider` есть свойство `margin: auto`. С ним флексбокс-потомки ведут себя именно так:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нет никаких лишних стилей. К .slider я подключаю slick слайдер и думал, что возможно он создает лишние стили. Но при отключении слайдера ничего не менятся. Т.е у меня потомок имеет только width